# Bluetooth isnt working ASUS X401a running Raring 13.04

Tags: 13.04, bluetooth, asus

My bluetooth is not working. I have searched many threads and looked at many solutions and I can't seem to find anything. Help would be much appreciated.

I have a Asus X401A running Ubuntu 13.04 raring

If i type in rfkill list:

```
    0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

The output of lsmod is:

```
    bluetooth             228619  10 bnep,rfcomm
```

The output of hcitool dev is:

```
    Devices: *no devices*
```

The output of dmesg | tail:

```
      [  748.119475] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
      [  748.119479] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
      [  748.119483] ath: Country alpha2 being used: GB
      [  748.119486] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
      [  748.119513] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: GB
      [  748.119516] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
      [  748.119522] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
      [  748.119526] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
      [  748.119531] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
      [  748.119537] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm)
```

Seriously dont know what do to, would love some help!!!

**UPDATE**

Also when I open up bluetooth manager, it lets me toggle the switch between on and off but will not let me change the visibilty so maybe the bluetooth is one but invisible to everyone ???

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the btusb kernel module, that might fix things:

```
sudo modprobe btusb
```

If that works, consider adding the btusb to the file `/etc/modules` to force loading it.

Comment: nope it didnt help