# Bluetooth driver problem causing lib/bluez/adapter.c:165:adapter_get_dbus_object_path: assertion failed

Tags: drivers, kernel, bluetooth

My Bluetooth keeps breaking. I noticed it wasn't working and ran `bt-device -l` which produced: `ERROR:lib/bluez/adapter.c:165:adapter_get_dbus_object_path: assertion failed: (ADAPTER_IS(self))`.

I tried `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth` which did not work. I then reloaded the kernel module with:

```
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

which fixed it. I am asking if anyone knows a permanent solution to this.

I'm using 18.04, kernel 4.15.0-65-generic.

Comment: I have the same issue with my 18.04 5.3.0-40-generic.
did you find a solution?

Comment: [Consider adding the btusb kernel module to `/etc/modules`, to force loading it](https://askubuntu.com/a/290301/349837)